# Vuejs2- How to call a filter function from a method

Tags: vuejs2

I am using "moneyFormat" filter for formatting the currency value. It's formatting the values which is defined already. I want to format the dynamic values. Hence I have called the filter function through a method called "displayValue", but I am getting error

[image]

and the given input field also not updated.

Here is my code :

```
<template>
    <b-card>
        <div class="panel-body" id="app">
            <table class="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="width: 20px;">No.</th>
                        <th style="width: 330px;">Description</th>
                        <th style="width: 130px;" class="text-right">Charges</th>
                        <th style="width: 130px;">Total</th>
                        <th style="width: 130px;"></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr v-for="(row, index) in rows" :key="row.qty">
                        <td>
                            {{ index +1 }}
                        </td>
                        <td>

                        <select name="" id="" class="form-control" v-model="row.billChgDesc">
                            <option v-for="option in billChgDescOpt" v-bind:value="option.value" 
                                :key="option.value"> {{ option.text }} 
                            </option>
                        </select>
                        </td>

                                <td> 
                                  <input @input="displayValue" class="form-control text-right" type="text" v-model="row.charges"  data-type="currency" v-validate="'required'" :name="'charges' + index">
                                     <span v-show="vErrors.has('charges' + index)" class="is-danger">{{ vErrors.first('charges' + index) }}</span>
                                <td>
                                    <input class="form-control text-right" :value="row.qty * row.charges | moneyFormat" number readonly />
                                    <input type="hidden" :value="row.qty * row.charges * row.tax / 100"  number/>
                                </td>

                                <td>
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" @click="addRow(index)"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
                                    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" @click="removeRow(index)"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3" class="text-right">DELIVERY</td>
                        <td colspan="1" class="text-right"><input class="form-control text-right" v-model="delivery" number/></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>

        </div>
    </b-card>
</template>

<script>
import Vue from 'vue'
import accounting from 'accounting'

export default {

filters:{
moneyFormat: function (val){
     if (val > 0) {
            return accounting.formatMoney(val, " ₹ ", 2, ",", ".");
        }
}
},
   data: function () {
    return {
        billChgDescOpt: [
            { value: '', text: 'Select' },
            { value: 'M', text: 'Maintenance Fee'},
            { value: 'W', text: 'Water Charges'},
            { value: 'P', text: 'Penalty Fee'},
            ],
        rows: [
            {qty: 5, billChgDesc: '', charges: 55.20, tax: 10},
            {qty: 19, billChgDesc: '', charges: 1255.20, tax: 20},
        ],
        grandtotal: 0,
        delivery: 40
    }

  },
    computed: {
        total: function () {
            var t = 0;
            $.each(this.rows, function (i, e) {
                t += accounting.unformat(e.total, ",");
            });
            return t;
        },
        taxtotal: function () {
            var tt = 0;
            $.each(this.rows, function (i, e) {
                tt += accounting.unformat(e.tax_amount, ",");
            });
            return tt;
        }
    },
    methods: {

        addRow: function (index) {
            try {
                this.rows.splice(index + 1, 0, {});
            } catch(e)
            {
                console.log(e);
            }
        },
        removeRow: function (index) {
            this.rows.splice(index, 1);
        },
        displayValue:function (e) {
            var value = e.target.value
         var a = this.filters.moneyFormat(value);
         return a;
        }
    }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.is-danger{
  color:  RED;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Did you solve your problem? It works? If yes, mark an answer as valid in order to mark as resolved and keep S.O clean. If no, try updating the question and we will try to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
this.$options.filters.moneyFormat(value)
```

Check: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-options

For global filters, first set:

```
Vue.prototype.$filters = Vue.options.filters
```

And then:

```
this.$filters.foo
```

**Edit:**

Looking closer your code, you are not using the `filter` as a Vue filter and only calling from one point (a method) instead of calling inline from HTML, maybe it's better that the method itself returns the value of the input, like:

```
displayValue: function (e) {
    var val = e.target.value
    if (val > 0) {
       return accounting.formatMoney(val, " ₹ ", 2, ",", ".");
    }
}
```

Did it work? Or the same error is shown? If yes, can you paste the error?

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yeah it's working. But the value is not reflecting inside the input element [Iam using "return a " for reflecting the updated value]

Comment: And I have tried " **var a = this.$options.filters.moneyFormat(value);
         this.$emit('input', a)** " this too

Comment: As you are binding the `row.charges` in the input, try changing this variable value in the method, like: `this.row.charges = this.$options.filter.moneyFormat(value)`. I think this way will update the value without a `return`. Or in the `e.target.value` directly.

Comment: I did. If I give like this, " **this.row.charges = this.$options.filter.moneyFormat(value)** ", it's throwing the same error again

Comment: I tried ur "displayValue" function instead of filter function, but samething happened again and the error is " **Illegal return statement** "

Comment: @sovalina, I have tried your's. It's working fine, but it's not formatting the value of dynamically added rows. How to access the same function for dynamically added rows

Comment: Try adding a return for the `else`. If this doen't work, can you share the `console.log()` of the return?

Answer (score 0):

As it's been said, if you want to use the filter, you need to do `this.$options.filters.moneyFormat(value)`

What you're trying to achieve it's rendered the moneyFormat inside an input and the value displayed is the `v-model`. It's this one you have to format.
So you can initialize a new data property filled with each `row.charges` formatted on mounted:

```js
data: function () {
  return {
    rows: [
      //...
    ],
    currentCharges: []
  }
},

mounted() {
  this.rows.forEach(row => {
    let formattedCharges = this.$options.filters.moneyFormat(row.charges)
    this.currentCharges.push(formattedCharges)
  })
},
```

and use this data to fulfill your inputs:

```html
<tr v-for="(row, index) in rows">
  <td> 
    <input v-model="currentCharges[index]" @input="displayValue($event, index)">
  <td>
```

To keep the current `row.charges` updated, reassign it when the v-model updates:

```js
methods: {
  displayValue:function (e, index) {
    // the target value is a string like this " ₹ 55.20"
    // split it and convert the last element to Float type
    let arrValue = e.target.value.split(" ")
    let parseValue = parseFloat(arrValue[arrValue.length -1])

    // reassign the row.charges with the new float value
    this.rows[index].charges = parseValue
  }
},
```